# WPF WebBrowser MinHeight

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

It seems the WPF WebBrowser control has a builtin minimum height of 150.

You can set a height explicitly and it will comply but in a * layout it won't resize to less than 150.

Simplified my xaml looks like this (stripped colors, borders, etc.)

edit1: added ItemsControl (seems to cause this or is related to the problem, doesn't matter if the webbrowser loads a html file or not)

```
    <ItemsControl>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <WebBrowser Grid.Row="0" Name="WebBrowserStartPage" Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/StartPage.html" />
            <ListBox Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Setting MinHeight seems to be ignored.
It there any other way to set the minimum height for resizing?

Comment: I just tested your example and it works like expected. ListBox and WebBrowser resizes equally to a height of 0. btw you are missing curly brackets in the itemsSource binding.

Comment: seems I have stripped to much of the xaml around... there are lots of other usercontrols and themed devexpress controls around... I will try to reproduce this in a small test application, thank you for the hint!

Comment: seems the ItemsControl causes that problem... the Grid is usually in an UserControl and the ItemsControl loads a List<> of these UserControls... I just tried to reduce the code to the most essential parts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more testing I found that setting the VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Disabled fixes that problem...

Maybe this helps someone who comes across this issue...

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
```

I still don't know why the WebBrowser stopped resizing at 150... Might be some magic Microsoft number?

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9996233/4503749) post the WebBrowser control is not a real WPF control. Maybe that causes the problem. Try use an other webbrowser like [WPF Chromium](http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/)