# Place image over Webbrowser Control Failure

Tags: wpf, image, browser, overlay

I have an image that needs to be placed over a `WebBrowser`. The problem is no matter what I do the image always ends up behind the `WebBrowser` control. I cant use Awesomium, a custom web browser control that uses Chrome instead of IE ActiveX as Awesomium cannot load XBAP files.

I have looked almost everywhere but I cannot find a proper solution to this problem.

How can I display an image over the WPF `WebBrowser` control?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the WPF [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) is implemented in a similar manner to Silverlight and WinRT (aka Windows 8 Metro).

The [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in Silverlight and [`WebView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) in WinRT/Metro are always on top in the Z-order. This is apparently due to them using the Trident ActiveX control. To work around the Z-order issue, the [`WebBrowserBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowserbrush%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and [`WebViewBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush.aspx) are provided.

Unfortunately, it does not look like WPF provides a brush for this purpose.

Searching around on the Internet, it looks like there are some who have had varying degrees of success in trying to mimic this brush behavior. However, this may not really help you as using any kind of brush removes interactivity with the rendered content.

Comment: You are a genius... but... Can you point me to the right direction perhaps a website or something like that or a resource or in any chance a custom web control besides awesomium that will allow me to do something like so ?

Comment: I have been searching around and so far I haven't found anything that would be much use. I'll keep looking and update if I find anything.

Comment: Thanks man cause what ive read up so far is that most people recommends others to use pop ups to overlay images but it is a no go for me

Comment: You might also try this, although I suspect this may create other issues: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/90cb3bf6-ca7a-4e8a-a539-957de1f939d9

Comment: There's also the popup approach which looks promising. Why is this a no go for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1073583/23234

Comment: Note this renderer. This might actually help implement the browser brush idea. http://www.codeplex.com/WPFWin32Renderer

Comment: Wow thanks man for all the help. Ouh the popup wont work cause the image has a call back to the original app. So the callback cannot be registered if it is on a pop up . and it will be out of place.... hey one last thing do you know how i can refresh the webpage through c#? like clicking on the refresh button on the internet explorer...

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I suspect refresh is achieved by calling `Navigate` on the URL currently being shown.

Answer (score 1):

WPF webbrowser is not a REAL WPF Control but uses some HwndHost to show some IE goodies.
This leads to the "WPF Airspace" Problem (which should be fixed with .net 4.5).
The only option to display an image above the webbrowser control is to put it in a Popup above the webrowser.
Popups have their own Win32 Hwnd and therefore have their own "Airspace".

just do something like

```
<WebBrowser Name="web">
</WebBrowser>
<Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=web}" Placement="Center" IsOpen="true">
 <Image Source="blub.png"/>
</Popup>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not solved in WPF 4.5. There was some information in some forums, such the below mentioned properties would be available with the 4.5 version of web browser control, however the plan has been dropped. So you need to handle the airspace issue by yourself.

```
WebBrowser.CompositionMode = System.Windows.Interop.CompositionMode.Full; WebBrowser.IsRedirected = true;
```

The workaround that you could do is by making the height of the web browser control to zero, when some other control comes in front of Web browser control.

Find sample code below,

Assume, you have a web browser control in Mainwindow. When you perform some action,, eg: click a button you have another user control which comes above MainWindow. However, because of Airspace issue the web browser doesn't sit in its parent control and comes on top of your control.

FIX: The standard fix is you can set the height of web browser to zero when you trigger some other control over it depends upon your scenario. Below, there is a sample implementation.

In MainWindow.Xaml include the events.

```
Activated="Window_Activated"
Deactivated="Window_Deactivated"
```

In Xaml.cs handle the scenario by setting the height.

```
private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wb.Height = double.NaN;
}

private void Window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    wb.Height = 0;
}
```