# WPF ClipToBounds=True but not clipping

Tags: wpf, xaml, clipping

EDIT: This question is a duplicate of [WPF WebBrowser (3.5 SP1) Always on top - other suggestion to display HTML in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980334/wpf-webbrowser-3-5-sp1-always-on-top-other-suggestion-to-display-html-in-wpf)

I have the following. It is not clipping. Specifically, if I use the ScrollViewer to scroll the WebBrowser outside of the region occupied by the ScrollViewer, the WebBrowser is not clipped. I want it to be clipped. What am I missing?

```
<UniformGrid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Columns="1" Rows="2">
  <avalonEdit:<!-- various stuff omitted here-->>
  <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Border Height="2000" Background="Green" ClipToBounds="True">
      <WebBrowser x:Name="EditorBrowser"
                  y:HTMLReferenceEditor.Html="{Binding Document.Text, ElementName=TextEditor}"/>
    </Border>
  </ScrollViewer>
</UniformGrid>
```

Problem illustrated by the image below.

[image]

Comment: Does apply `ClipToBounds="true"` to `WebBrowser` help? If not, maybe a look into the ControlTemplate of WebBrowser might help.

Comment: try the debugger in vs2015 you can go through the visual tree and see the exact property values after themes.

Comment: Yes, the ScrollViewer, Border, and WebBrowser all have ClipToBounds=True

Comment: Interestingly, if I replace the WebBrowser with a simple Border, it does clip. So it has to have something to do with the behavior of WebBrowser.